# JMeter: New data to be created automatically in HTTP Request

Tags: api, jmeter, bulk

I need to create a http request in JMeter to submit bulk API requests.

Inorder to do that, I have created a code in RunSwift tool to generate the bulk API requests and then aligned the requests in https://jsonlint.com website and then copied/pasted them in Jmeter.

**What I am trying to Achieve:**

Currently, if I have to submit 3-4 batches of API requests every 15 min, I am manually performing the above activities and replacing the content every time in HTTP request.

I was given a requirement that the batch job should submit 200 request every 15 min for continuous 8 hrs.

I feel that my current approach is not sustainable as I have to replace the content 32 times (every 15 min for 8 hrs).

Hence I would like to take your suggestion on how i can refresh the data in the API request every 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

Replace hard-coded values like user name, address, phone, email, whatever with random entities which will be generated on the fly using the following JMeter Functions:

- [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - generates a random integer within the given range
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - generates a random string from given input characters
- [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) - generates an unique [GUID structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)
- [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - returns current timestamp

You can inline JMeter Functions directly into your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler body like:

[image: JMeter Using Functions in Request Body]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.